# dbContext in Constructor vs Initialize

Tags: c#, linq

I am confused as to what would be better practice.  This application is in .net 4.5.1 using MVC 4.  When we initialize the database in a controller we do it this way

```cs
private EntitiesModel _dbContext;

protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    _dbContext = new CompanyContextFactory().GetContextPerRequest();
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    _dbContext.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

I usually initialize the database in the controller like this:

```cs
private EntitiesModel _dbContext;

public ClientsController()
{
      _dbContext = new CompanyContextFactory().GetContextPerRequest();
}
```

Which one is better practice?  I don't have the option to use `using` statements so I figured I'd put it in the constructor.  Will having it done the first way cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely there is something else going on here and in your codebase you need to create an instance of `DbContext` per `HttpRequest`. In ASP.NET MVC, the `HttpContext` is not assigned at the point when the controller class instance is constructed hence why there would be a need to create the instance within the controller action method.

None of the above is possible to prove though from the code you posted, so as it stands now, it would actually be better to take advantage of dependency injection instead of constructing the `DbContext` anywhere in the controller class.